# Permission errors backing up entire system using rsnapshot over local server

Tags: rsync, backup, webserver, rsnapshot

EDIT: the solution to this problem is the marked solution underneath + enabling `PermitRootLogin without-password`  in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

I'm trying to backup my entire system to my local server, but I even though I'm running rsnapshot as sudo, I get permission errors in /var/, /etc/ and /usr/. Is there a way to fix this? If there isn't, what's my best option to backup my system to my local server?

This is my rsnapshot.conf

```
config_version  1.2

###########################
# SNAPSHOT ROOT DIRECTORY #
###########################

snapshot_root   /home/gisbi/backup/

cmd_cp      /bin/cp

cmd_rm      /bin/rm

cmd_rsync   /usr/bin/rsync

cmd_ssh /usr/bin/ssh

cmd_logger  /usr/bin/logger

cmd_du      /usr/bin/du

#########################################
#     BACKUP LEVELS / INTERVALS         #
# Must be unique and in ascending order #
# e.g. alpha, beta, gamma, etc.         #
#########################################

#retain hourly  24
retain  daily   7
retain  weekly  4
retain  monthly 12

#logs

verbose     5

loglevel    4

logfile /var/log/rsnapshot.log

lockfile    /var/run/rsnapshot.pid

ssh_args    -p 22

#exclusions

exclude     /dev/*
exclude     /proc/*
exclude     /sys/*
exclude     /run/*
exclude     /var/tmp/*
exclude     /var/run/*
exclude     /tmp/*
exclude     /run/*
exclude     /mnt/*
exclude     /usr/portage/distfiles/*
exclude     /lost+found
exclude     /home/gisbi/Storage
exclude     /home/gisbi/.local/share/Trash/*

#location

backup  gisbi@192.168.1.15:/        popbackup/
```

EDIT: errors look like this

```
rsync: [sender] send_files failed to open "/usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-brf": Permission denied (13)
rsync: [sender] send_files failed to open "/usr/lib/cups/backend/implicitclass": Permission denied (13)
```

Comment: Could you add the errors to your question?

Comment: @mashuptwice yes sure, I'll add a few of them because they're too many, but they all look identical

Comment: Your "Edit" explaning you've enabled root logins with a password is a _very very_ bad idea. You've potentially just opened up your root account to cracking attempts via a guessable password

Comment: @roaima it did feel insecure, but before doing it I asked a question here asking if it was a good idea, and people said it wasn't a problem since the password-less access applied only to my home-server, which has access to my computer secured by ssh keys. If it's a bad practice, what else can I do?

Comment: Use ssh keys as recommended in my answer to you. But if the system is only accessible on your LAN it is indeed ok to open up to a root password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your relevant backup line

> ```
> backup  gisbi@192.168.1.15:/ popbackup/
> ```

You're running the source backup as `gisbi` rather than as root, so it cannot open the problematic files listed as errors.

I'd be inclined to run the source sender as root, and use `--fake-super` on the receiving side with a non-root account. This would go into the `rsync_long_args` value. Here are some of my typical working settings:

```
# Remember: command {TAB} arguments
#
rsync_short_args    -azHS
rsync_long_args     --delete --delete-excluded --numeric-ids --fake-super
…
backup              root@remoteHost:/ root/
```

When backing up with `root` as the remote user, you should use ssh public/private key authentication. (By default the `ssh` service disallows root logins by password. You can change this but it's really not recommended.) Check out `ssh-keygen -t ed25519` and other references here on [Unix&Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com), as well as the paper, [Comparing SSH Keys - RSA, DSA, ECDSA, or EdDSA?](https://goteleport.com/blog/comparing-ssh-keys/) by Kontsevoy.

Comment: Thanks! Do I put `--fake-super` in the rsync args in the rsnapshot.conf file? Also: when doing root@ it asks me for the password, but my user password doesn't work. What do I do?

Comment: @Gisbitus answer updated for you